# SSL no certificate

Tags: bash, wget, openssl, ssl, certificates

I'm trying to make a bash script who will check the SSL status of my web site client and return the error. But for every IP, `wget https://$ip:$port` gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: The certificate of 1.2.3.4 is not trusted
ERROR: The certificate of 1.2.3.4 hasn't got a know issuer
```

When I try with Firefox I have the certificate for each IP. So I tried to dump the Firefox CA to a repository like this:

```
wget http://$ip:$port --ca-directory=(directory of CA from Firefox)
```

But it doesn't change anything.

I think, `wget` doesn't find SSL certificate and I don't know to get them.

How can I get the certificate information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically SSL certificates are issued to hostnames like `www.example.com` and not to IP-adresses. 

Therefore when you use the IP-address you get a mismatch between the URL you're accessing and the hostname the certificate was issued to.

Second the CA directory from firefox may not be suitable, as according to the man page wget requires:

> **--ca-directory=directory** Specifies directory containing CA certificates in PEM format.  Each
>             file contains one CA certificate, and the file name is based on a
>             hash value derived from the certificate. ...

I think that wget uses the openssl libraries, possibly making that a more verbose utility to check on the certificate status, for example in a query to determine the expiry date of a SSL certificate:

```
 echo "GET /" | openssl s_client -connect servername:port  | openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know for the name server and ip but I have only ip in file and i have to check if the SSL certificate is still valid, but lots of them send me an error about wildcard. I don't care about this error. And about the -ca-directory option, I have make a copy of CA from Firefox (*.pem) in the /etc/ssl/certs folder.

Comment: If you only care about the expiry date; the script in my answer will also work on ip-addresses. You might want to suppress the STDERR with `2>/dev/null` though.

Comment: About ` echo "GET /" ... -noout -dates` it look like to give me exactly what I am looking for, Thanks you again  @HBruijn. But i still doesn't understand why wget didn't accept my CA file !

Comment: Either you specify a CA file with a single certificate, or a directory, which contains a number of files for different CA's. In that directory wget (and openssl) look for the CA certificate not by scanning all files in that directory, nor by the name of the CA, but by the hash value of the CA subject name. Typically you create a symlink to cafile.cert with the output of  `openssl x509 -subject_hash -in cafile.cert` as the name.

Comment: I don't fully understand. You said openssl cmd is looking for a CA hash. In cafile.cert, I have to put the hash of all CA I have ?

Comment: wget/openssl can look either in a single file (which can contain multiple CA certs, not just one) or a directory containing multiple files each containing one cert and having a filename or linkname that is the subject-hash, *plus ".0"*. See --ca-certificate and --ca-directory in http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html section 2.8. The one-file approach is easier to set up, especially for testing.

Comment: You don't need the `echo "GET /"`. SSL negotiation is performed before http. `openssl s_client -connect servername:port </dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates`